# принципы работы QTcpSocket, или почему для одного и того же количества пакетов происходит разное количество вызовов readyRead

Tags: c++, qt, сеть

**Общее описание**: При разработке сетевой программы на TCP обнаружил интересную закономерность. Вызов сигнала `readyRead` происходит разное количество раз для одного и того же кол-ва пакетов.

В описании сигнала `readyRead`[Qt документация](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead) говорит:

> This signal is emitted once every time new data is available for reading from the device's current read channel.

Исходя из того, что написано в документации, я ожидаю следующего поведения: приходит пакет = новые данные пришли на девайс = *emit* сигнала. Тогда, мне не понятно, почему для 4-х пакетов (из *WireShark*) количество вызовов `readyRead` колеблется от 2 до 4 (из вывода приложения в *QtCreator*).

**Ключевой вопрос**: Как можно объяснить такое поведение, что в сниффере я получаю всегда 4 пакета, а количество вызовов `readyRead` колеблется от 2 до 4?

---

**Технические детали**: На "той стороне" сидит недо-сервер, который просто отправляет обратно то, что получил. На клиентской стороне некое подобие асинхронного сокета:

```
// asyncsocket.h
class AsyncSocket
{
public:
    void send(const QByteArray &msg);

public slots:
    void readyRead();

private:
    QTcpSocket *socket;
};

// asyncsocket.cpp
void AsyncSocket::send(const QByteArray &msg)
{
    if (socket->state() == QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState)
        socket->write(msg, msg.size());
}

void AsyncSocket::readyRead()
{
    qDebug() << "slot readyRead" << socket->bytesAvailable();
}
```

По нажатию на кнопку вызывается метод `send` с сообщением размером 3900 байт, а сервер пересылает его обратно.

Вывод приложения:

```
----- button clicked ------ 
slot readyRead 1460 
slot readyRead 3508 
slot readyRead 3900 
----- button clicked ------ 
slot readyRead 2048 
slot readyRead 3508 
slot readyRead 3900 
----- button clicked ------ 
slot readyRead 2048 
slot readyRead 3900
----- button clicked ------ 
slot readyRead 1460 
slot readyRead 2048 
slot readyRead 3508 
slot readyRead 3900
```

Вывод WireShark (служебные пакеты опущены для упрощения):

```
#  |     Source    |  Destination  | Prot| len  | Info
25 | 192.168.51.57 | 192.168.51.63 | TCP | 3954 | 50597 → 9025 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=3900

27 | 192.168.51.63 | 192.168.51.57 | TCP | 1514 | 9025 → 50597 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=3901 Win=7300 Len=1460
28 | 192.168.51.63 | 192.168.51.57 | TCP |  642 | 9025 → 50597 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1461 Ack=3901 Win=7300 Len=588
30 | 192.168.51.63 | 192.168.51.57 | TCP | 1514 | 9025 → 50597 [ACK] Seq=2049 Ack=3901 Win=7300 Len=1460
31 | 192.168.51.63 | 192.168.51.57 | TCP |  446 | 9025 → 50597 [PSH, ACK] Seq=3509 Ack=3901 Win=7300 Len=392
```

Причем картина в сниффере всегда одинаковая. Ушел 1 пакет, пришло 4.

Comment: Снифер пакеты показывает. А TcpSocket данные, которые с помощью этих пакетов передаются. Ну то есть снифер парсит пакеты (заголовки) и показывает именно пакеты. TcpSocket предоставляет механизм по чтению данных, и судя по логам, все корректно - все 3900 байт вам в итоге приходят.

Comment: @vegorov, да, вы правы. Все работает корректно. И к TcpSocket "претензий" нет никаких. Но вопрос не в том, *что приходит*. Вопрос в том, *как приходит*.  Мне непонятно, почему в одном случае вызов сигнала происходит 4 раза (см. последний вызов в логах), а в другом - 2 раза (см. предпоследний вызов). Ведь пакетов с данными то четыре. Каждый пакет с данными содержит в себе что-то полезное, что сокет успешно записывает в свой буфер. Однако, судя по "показаниям" сниффера... не каждая запись в буфер порождает `readyRead`. (не могут же два разных пакета записаться в буфер одной записью.. по идее)

Comment: @goldstar_labs речь не об этом, а о том что пакета всегда 4 (на уровне протокола), а сокет сигнализирует не по границе пакетов. Bogdan: Видимо он и не должен так делать. Всё что он должен делать - сигнализировать о том, что у него появились новые данные, которые вы до этого не видели. Ваше дело теперь - разобрать эти данные. Я просто не понимаю почему Вас это так беспокоит (большая часть комментария адресована ТС)

Comment: Ведь если вам нужно парсить пакеты TCP, то QTcpSocket вам не поможет, для этого видимо нужно спустить на уровень ниже. TCP поверх IP бегает ? Видимо на уровень IP протокола

Comment: @vegorov, видимо я неправильно понял вопрос) ликвидируюсь)

Comment: @vegorov, мне не нужно парсить TCP. Это больше практический интерес и расширение кругозора, желание не просто работать "болгаркой", но и знать, как она устроена. Просто по документации  "сигнал вызывается единожды, когда новые данные доступны для чтения.."  ну или как-то примерно так. Следовательно, в теории: новый пакет с данными - новые данные доступны для чтения - новый readyRead. На практике получилось иначе, и именно это не дает покоя. Хочется понять, почему..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для начала, с логической точки зрения, общение по tcp представляет из себя двунаправленный неделимый поток байт. Т.е. то, на какие сегменты разбиваются сообщения при передаче не должно интересовать высокоуровневого пользователя практически никогда, но он должен быть готов к тому, что сообщение может дробиться как-угодно мелко.

> Как можно объяснить такое поведение, что в сниффере я получаю всегда 4 пакета, а количество вызовов readyRead колеблется от 2 до 4?

Ничего примечательного. Здесь обычная гонка. Возможная последовательность действий:

1. *Ядро* получает пакет №1.
2. *Ядро* пробуждает процесс *приложения* спящий на `poll()`'е.
3. *Приложение* обрабатывает возврат из `poll()`'a, посылается Qt'шный сигнал.
4. *Приложение* запрашивает данные из сокета.
5. *Ядро* получает пакет №2.

   ...

Ни кто не гарантирует, что пункт 5 не произойдёт в **любой** момент раньше, чем пункты 2—4 и в таком случае пакеты естественным образом «склеятся».